# If multiple programs are reading from a FIFO, what guarantees are available in order-of-receipt?

Tags: bash, named-pipes, mkfifo

Say I make a named pipe:

```
mkfifo foo

cat foo
cat foo

echo "stuff" > "$foo"
```

is there any guarantee that the first call to cat will receive the data first?

Comment: As this is currently written, the second `cat foo` won't start *at all* until the first one exits, and the `echo` won't run until *both* `cat`s are no longer active. Please make sure your test case is a real [mcve], which someone else can run without changes to observe the behavior you're interested in.

Comment: Also the FIFO foo will never receive any data.

Comment: ...unless someone has run `foo=foo`, that is, such that `"$foo"` evaluates to `foo`. :)

Comment: ...if in the real-world case some of these are *background* processes, the code is missing essential details. `cat foo & cat foo &` has an entirely different set of guarantees from `{ cat foo; cat foo; } &`. We need a reproducer that accurately generates the case for which you want to understand the guarantees available.